# Select input tag in the same row from a table on clicking an anchor tag in the same row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, htmltable-control

Sample Html(This only contains one of many more row).

```
<table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_categoryTable" class="categoryTable sortAsc editInputs" border="0">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td>8</td>
     <td>
     <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl17" type="text" value="307349_335692806541952_16061425_n.jpg" readonly="readonly" />
    </td>
    <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl18" type="text" value="key1 " readonly="readonly" /></td>
    <td>3/28/2013</td>
    <td>.jpg</td>
    <td>28120</td>
    <td><a href="download.aspx filename=307349_335692806541952_16061425_n.jpg&type=image">307349_335692806541952_16061425_n.jpg</a></td>
    <td>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="editLinkClass">Edit </a><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="deletetLinkClass"> Delete</a><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="updateLinkClass" style="display:none;">Update</a><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="cancelLinkClass" style="display:none;"> Cancel</a>
    </td>
    <tr>
    </tbody>
```

My Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("document ready")
            $(".categoryTable tr td a").click (function (event) {
                console.log($(this).text() + "click detected");
                if ($(this).text() === "Edit ") {//compare with "Edit " not "Edit"
                    console.log("Edit");
                    console.log($(this).parent().parent().children('td input').text());
                    $(this).siblings(".deletetLinkClass").attr("style", "display:none");
                    $(this).siblings(".updateLinkClass").attr("style", "display:;");
                    $(this).siblings(".cancelLinkClass").attr("style", "display:;");
                    $(this).attr("style", "display:none")
                }
                else
                    console.log("no EDit");
            });
        });
```

What i am trying to do is select the input tags in the same row `tr` but different `td` on click of an anchor tag in the same row. I have tried a lot of combinations of the following jQuery statement with no success. Please Help.
`$(this).parent().parent().children('td input').text()` Here `this` represents the clicked anchor tag. To be more clear i don't want to select all the input tags in the table, just the ones in the same row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `parents()` and `find()`.

and to get the value of input, use `val()` and not `text()` ..

```
$(this).parent().parent().children('td input').text();
                                           //--^^^^^^---here
```

try this

```
var inputs=$(this).parents('tr').find('input');
$.each(inputs,function(){  //<---- loop since you have multiple input
    console.log($(this).val()); //.val() since val() is used to get the input value..
})
```

or using `closest()`and `find()`.

```
var inputs=$(this).closest('tr').find('input');
```

using context

```
var inputs = $('td input', $(this).closest('tr')).val();
```

[working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/48UnN/)

Comment: it worked...also i kinda figured out text() wasn't working on the input tags so i used $(this).prop("value") which worked.

Comment: why you ain't using val().. prop works though... but val() is there for this reason.. to get the value of the input

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
$('td input', $(this).closest('tr')).val();
```

Comment: your getting the value of input here... and `.text()` won't work at all

Comment: Sorry, i didn't notice about that.. I've edited my answer. Thanks for pointing out. :)

Comment: @bipen yea i figured that out

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to find input from given row

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td input').text()
```